# Automatic height resize of an iframe, problems with chrome and safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I need to include an iframe in a page and I want to calculate the correct height and adjust it in order to avoid displaying the vertical scrollbar. I want to display the horizontal scrollbar, though, if needed.

I've found several posts about this problem, but no one works 100%. This is a very common approach I've seen:

```
$(document).ready(function() {      
$('iframe').load(function() {
$("#your-iframe-id").height($("#your-iframe-id").contents().find("html").height()+35);
});
})

<iframe id="your-iframe-id" style="width:100%;border:0;" src="test.php"></iframe>
```

The problem I've found with this approach is that, with Safari and Chrome, if, navigating into the iframe, I visit a page which is shorter than the previous one, the height of the frame is still the one of the taller page. If, instead, you navigate from a short page to a tall one, everything is working fine. Firefox doesn't have this problem; I didn't try with IE and Opera.

Any help is really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Edit: trying with a different set of pages in the iframe (actually iframing an entire PHP app, the first test was just with very simple html pages), also firefox suffers from the same problem, I don't know why. Furthermore, firefox in this case always shows the vertical scrollbar, because for some reason the height it calculated is always a few pixels less than the real one. Changing +35 with +45 or something like that doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: Regarding the "few pixels less" problem - I found that if there's a border/padding set on the `body` of an iframe - you need to wait (timeout, etc) before they are included in height calculations.

Regarding the rest of the problem - I'm still trying to pin it down, but it does feel like a Chrome bug - especially considering that the reduced test case (just a div changing its size) does work correctly - which means there are other factors at play...

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
    var resizeHandle = function()
    {
        var theFrame = $('.window-content-wrapper', parent.document.body);
        theFrame.height($(document).height());      
        var theFrame = $('.window-content', parent.document.body);
        theFrame.height($(document).height());
    };
</script>

<iframe id ="home"  onResize="resizeHandle()" onload="resizeHandle()" style="width:100%;border:0;" src="test.php"></iframe>
```

Comment: chrome required a manual resize of the containing window for me before the resize handling solution would work in some cases